# Install Tailwind CSS every time we create a new project?

Tags: css, tailwind-css

Do we need to install tailwind css and its files in every new project we start in every new folder?

I am not sure if it is how its done or is there any other possible way?
And on a live server will saving the file refresh the website with new styles? Or do we have to run npm again and again

Comment: That all depends on the structure of all of your projects. Generally, you would just create one project that handles the styling, and then import the generated CSS into your other projects. Special use-cases may require different solutions (e.g. presets, plugins, etc).

Answer (score 0):

1. Ya you do have to install tailwind in every "new" project.
2. If you have installed tailwind in your project then you won't have stop and start server again and again for tailwind to take effect, it will work.

Hope this helps.